# How to turn on and turn off double-right-click on Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When you double-right-click, the map will zoom in.

How do I turn this off/on. Same goes for double-left-click.

Answer (score 1):

To disable in v3, pass `disableDoubleClickZoom : true` in the MapOptions

refer to: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html), there is no "right double click" event defined. There is a "rightclick", a standard (left) "click", and a (left) "dblclick". What is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to have been removed from v3.. here it is mentioned in v2

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html

singlerightclick(point:GPoint, src:Element, overlay?:GOverlay)

This event is fired when the DOM contextmenu event is fired on the map container. If the right click was on a marker or other clickable overlay, then the overlay is passed to the event handler in the overlay argument. The pixel coordinates (in the DOM element that holds the map) of the point that was right clicked and the source element of the DOM event are passed in the point and src arguments respectively. Note that if it is a double right click and double click to zoom is enabled, then the map zooms out and no singlerightclick event is fired. If, however, double click to zoom is disabled, two singlerightclick events will be fired.